# Trying to display just the time

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to select just the time in the Datetime variable using sqlite but it doesn't work , it shows me this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
        at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
        at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:451)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
        at com.nextinnovation.pt.barcodescanner.adapter.NewsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(NewsAdapter.java:85)
        at com.nextinnovation.pt.barcodescanner.adapter.NewsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(NewsAdapter.java:25)
```

This is my method :

```
    public Cursor getDate(Product produit){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select time(created_at) from " + TABLE_PRODUCT, null);
        return res;
    }
```

and this is where I call it :

```
Cursor date = db.getDate(mData.get(position));
        if (date.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                data = date.getString(date.getColumnIndex("created_at"));
                newsViewHolder.tv_date.setText(data);
                // do what ever you want here
            }while(date.moveToNext());
        }
        date.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLite, you can use `strftime()`:

```
strftime('%H:%M:%S', created_at) as created_at
```

Note that you need to alias the column returned by the expression so you can later on access it by name:

```
Cursor res = db.rawQuery(
    "select strftime('%H:%M:%S', created_at) as created_at from " + TABLE_PRODUCT, 
    null
);
```

Comment: thank you but please I want to diplay like time and date for example:yesterday on 12h00  how can I do this ?